# Facebook Like button Widget Comment box overflow the footer content

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

My facebook widget code:

```
<div class="fb-like " data-href="https://www.facebook.com/name" data-width="15" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

My problem is:i put this facebook like button in my footer content.When i click like button after login facebook it's show comment box.This comment box overflow the footer height or extend for footer height.how to solve this problem.[image]

Comment: First of all you should describe the style / behavior you'd like to get :)  

best thing would be a image as a blueprint

Comment: i want change position of comment box window.change window top of the footer content.it's possible.